# Mouse move incredibly slow in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am seeing an incredibly slow call to what appear to be mouse move events when moving the mouse cursor over my application. Here's what the Firefox javascript profiler says:

[image]

Th result is that drawing shapes if very slow (it even freezes sometimes when I move the mouse cursor quickly), although I only have 10 shapes on the screen...

I guess there's something wrong with my code, but the thing is that I don't even need any mouse interaction, my application is keyboard-only. Is there a way to prevent KineticJS from doing mouse events check? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, found it, I just have to call hitGraphEnabled(false) on all my layers, and no more problems.